# installing Pyqt5 on windows 10

Tags: sandbox, pyqt5

I downloaded the file from  [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x32-2.exe) and I have already disabled the chrome sandbox,but still facing the same problem.

[image]

Comment: The Chromium sandbox is most likely unrelated to this, and disabling it reduces Chrome's security, so I'd really advise to not do that. The error you see here ("Quick Heal"?) sounds more like some bad security product running on your machine.

Comment: Do you have any way out..? and yes, it does put my computer at risk, i agree.

Comment: What browser are you running exactly? What application is displaying this "Quick Heal" thing?

Comment: Google chrome,Pyqt5 is displaying this note,but i guess i have got a way to solve it,just by disabling the anti-virus's sandbox , we can install it.